# How to send a string from AngularJS to multiple Springboot Microservice(s)?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, microservices

I can't share code because I'm working on an internal school project. But I am trying to learn how to pass a simple piece of data in the body of an Angular application across Spring Boot Applications, sequentially.

This is the application flow:

1. **Angular JS/Typescript** front end needs to send a defined number=123 to Spring Boot **Microservice A**
2. Then Spring Boot **Microservice A** needs to send that defined number=123 to **Microservice B**

Essentially, the defined number=123, which is initialized in Angular, needs to make a POST request to Microservice A, then Microservice A needs to send this same number to Microservice B.

Thus, Microservice A acts as a messenger - how can I get Microservice A to retrieve this defined number from AngularJS and then pass it to Microservice B, if it's only job is to act as a messenger?

Comment: so backendA consume backendB's service isn't work?

Comment: the simple way is using REST API. from angular call REST API on Microservice A then microservice A call REST API on microservice B.

Comment: @paranaaan Sorry, not sure what you mean. My question is, how does backendA consume the string from the frontend and then pass it directly to backendB?

Comment: @wahyuekohadisaputro Correct, but how does Microservice A retrieve the string from Angular and pass that same string to Microservice B? Sorry it's my first time working with Springboot

Comment: Oh, I see. You need to looking for `REST API` between Frontend and Backend, and Backend and Backend. Both of them have a bit different to concern but overall is still the same.

Comment: @paranaaan Can you help me on that? Can you explain further? How does backendA retrieve the string from angular and then pass that retrieved string to backendB?

Comment: you can get sourcode from internet about example of REST API on spring boot, then you can try the API using POSTMAN as a REST client. in general you can pass parameter using HTTP POST or HTTP GET .  example rest api : https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-rest-api-with-spring-boot

Comment: @anonymousowl It'll be a lot to know. The fastest way to implement is follow some simple on the internet like wahyu eko hadi saputro's post, and then modify it to meet your requirement after it.

Comment: @wahyuekohadisaputro thanks, but  how does microservice-A know the value of the string variable, in order to make a POST request to microservice-B? The value of the string variable will only be defined in frontend/Angular.

Comment: @paranaaan Yes, but I already created the springboot app, but how does microservice-A know the value of the string variable, in order to make a POST request to microservice-B? The value of the string variable is only defined in Angular

Comment: Do the serviceA receive string from Angular?

Comment: @paranaaan Yes serviceA can only receive the string from Angular

Comment: usually the rest POST communication is using JSON format: example { "name" : "john" }, this json format will be converted by spring boot to be object that contain string variable name.  example : https://springframework.guru/requestbody-annotation/

Comment: then serviceA can take that string to consume serviceB's api?

Comment: @paranaaan yes, but how does serviceA know the value of that string, when it is defined in the Angular body POST request?

Comment: @wahyuekohadisaputro i see, but will serviceA know the value of that string, when it is defined in the Angular body POST request?

Comment: This is how: https://stackabuse.com/get-http-post-body-in-spring/